# spring3 empty modelAttribute received by controller when posted form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I om fairly new to spring and am now trying to develop a simple webshop demo application in spring3.
In the application i have defined an ArticleBean with the necessary getters and setters ( articleNumber , articleName,  articleDescription , articlePrice , articleCategory ).
An OrderlineBean contains the attributes quantity (Integer) and article (ArticleBean)
A Cart has the attribute orderlines of type HashMap()

The following part of the jsp results in a correct rendered form. e.g. the article data is correctly shown.

```
            <form:form method="post" action="updatecart.htm" modelAttribute="subStock">
                <c:forEach var="orderline" items="${subStock.orderlines}" varStatus="status">

                    <div id="orderLine">
                        <input hidden="true" name="orderline.key" value="${orderline.key}"/>
                        <div class="articleName"><p>${orderline.value.article.articleName}</p></div>

                        <div class="articleOrderedItems">
                            <select name="orderline[${orderline.key}].value.quantity">
                                <c:forEach begin="0" end="${orderline.value.quantity}" var="items">
                                    <option value="${items}">${items}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                            <div class="articlePrice">
                                <fmt:formatNumber minIntegerDigits="1"  maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" type="number" var="amount" value="${orderline.value.article.articlePrice/100}"/>
                                <p>&#8364; ${amount}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="articleDescription"><p>${orderline.value.article.articleDescription}</p></div>
                    </div>                           
                </c:forEach>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
            </form:form>
```

When posting the form, the number of orderlines in attribute subStock is 0 when processed by ModelAndView updateCart in the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatecart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateCart(Map map, @ModelAttribute("subStock") Cart subStock) {

    System.out.println("SantosController /updatecart POST") ;  
    System.out.println(subStock.size()) ;
    HashMap<String,OrderlineBean> orderlines = subStock.getOrderlines() ;
    Iterator orders = orderlines.keySet().iterator() ;
    while (orders.hasNext()) {
        String articleID = (String) orders.next() ;
        OrderlineBean orderline = orderlines.get(articleID) ;
        System.out.println(orderline.getArticle().getArticleDescription() + " )" + orderline.getQuantity() + ")") ;
    }

    DbMapper db = new DbMapper() ;

    // Set container URL
    map.put("containerURL","content_default.jsp" ) ;

    return new ModelAndView("santos_index"); 
}
```

Can anyone any help to get me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Peter

I have simplyfied the jsp form, still the same results though...

```
                            <form:form method="post" action="updatecart.htm" modelAttribute="subStock">
                                <c:forEach var="orderline" items="${subStock.orderlines}" varStatus="status">
                                    <input name="orderline['${orderline.key}']" value="${orderline.value}"/>
                                </c:forEach>
                                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
                            </form:form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the name be orderlines?

Comment: The name of your element is wrong. Use the spring `<form:input ../>` tag instead of the plain `input` tag.